# unable to repair GRUB after trying everything possible

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I initially had a windows and ubuntu dual boot in legacy mode which was working fine without any issues but then, after installing tlp battery saver and nvidia bumblebee i got an error message of 'environment block too small' every time I tried to use ubutnu. I wiped my harddisk completely and re installed ubuntu but the problem persisted, I tried everything to fix the error boot repair, re installing grub etc but nothing worked. What should I do now? Will replacing my hard disk solve the problem? I desperately need an answer because I'm very dependent on my laptop and need it to function properly.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-what-does-error-environment-block-too-small-on-booting-up-laptop-mean-how-is-it-resolved/28026)? You can do it, I guess, from a live-usb system.

Comment: @Hi-Angel yes. Doesn't work either. Can you confirm for me if replacing the hard disk will solve the problem? I just want to know if there's some solution, even if it is overkill.

Comment: Given you wiped out the disk, and the problem persist — I wouldn't hold a breath that it gonna work. Instead, try 2 other things. First, try if [Fedora](https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/) installation will work for you. If it has the same problem, then report a bug to both distributions — hopefully, someone will reply. It's just that from subjective experience with Fedora you has more chance of getting an answer — I regularly hear about Red Hat's contributions and QA on news sites, but rarely if ever do about Canonical's one.

Comment: @Hi-Angel. So what you're saying is that using some other OS might work? would it work if I wiped my hard disk again and installed windows?

Comment: Fedora is not "another os", it's just another GNU/Linux distro. It consist of same components as Ubuntu *(except of packaging system and the installer)*, but more recent ones, and from my experience it has better QA. With regard to your specific problem: Fedora has a different installer too, so it's possible the problem might go away.